# Jasmine unit test using injection

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In this test I am unsure why you need to set the angular variable to the  injection params in these 2 lines. Is it because the injection doesn't automatically assign the  $compile and  $rootScope?

```
 $compile = $c;
      $rootScope = $r;
```

from

```
describe("Unit: Testing Directives", function() {

  var $compile, $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  beforeEach(inject(
    ['$compile','$rootScope', function($c, $r) {
      $compile = $c;
      $rootScope = $r;
    }]
  ));

  it("should display the welcome text properly", function() {
    var element = $compile('<div data-app-welcome>User</div>')($rootScope);
    expect(element.html()).to.match(/Welcome/i);
  })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this it works for me:

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $http = $injector.get('$http');
        $q = $injector.get('$q');
}));
```